# sklearn LinearRegression reports error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Why doesn't this work in python?

```
    x = []
    y = []
    for ii in range(0,100):
        x.append(ii)
        y.append(ii)
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x, y)
    clf.predict(101)
```

I get the error "tuple index out of range"

Comment: X should be 2-dimensional array,  not 1-dimensional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list for each row so that in the end you have a 2D structure [[0], [1], [2], ...]:

```
x = []
y = []
for ii in range(0,100):
    x.append([ii])    <-----
    y.append(ii)
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(x, y)
clf.predict(101)
```

**Output:**

array([ 101.])